# Reference Request -- Galois theory of local fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

I've been trying to read the following note:

> [http://bicmr.pku.edu.cn/~lxiao/2020fall/Lecture1.pdf](http://bicmr.pku.edu.cn/%7Elxiao/2020fall/Lecture1.pdf)

On the *page 5 - 6*, there is a brief review on the Galois theory of local fields. I'm trying to understand the things there, e.g. unramified extension, tamely ramified extension (and so on) of the field $K$, where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

**In this post, I'm trying to find a detailed textbook to read things related to that**.

I've been reading Serre's classical book "*local fields*" these days, but haven't found explicit proofs of the facts in the note. (Although so many people cited this book for details.) If there are indeed things on such topics, I'm hoping someone to tell me where they are and what to read (or what to skip) to reach the results.

I have turned to several notes, namely

> NOTE for the MSRI summer school: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5c376d9cdfdb5c4f7a7e0377
> (Course webpage: [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/MSRI/](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/MSRI/))

and

> NOTE for the Arizona Winter School 2013
> [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~tsg/Index_files/ArizonaWinterSchool2013.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Etsg/Index_files/ArizonaWinterSchool2013.pdf)
> (Course webpage: [https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2013/index.html](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eswc/aws/2013/index.html))

But neither of them contains details on such things.

Thank you for commenting and answering! :)

Comment: Search for tamely ramified here on MSE (then wildly ramified if you are courageous) you'll find many questions with examples

Comment: _"A Gentle Course in Local Class Field Theory"_ by  Pierre Guillot.

Comment: What is your background? For example, have you taken a first course in algebraic number theory, so that you know what it for a prime to ramify in a number field? This type of material usually shows up in a second course in ANT

Comment: @Mathmo123 I've finished reading Milne's note *Algebraic Number Theory*, which covers prime factorization (including the ramification theory, e.g. decomposition/inertia groups), finiteness of ideal class group, Dirichlet's unit theorem, etc. . I have also learnt some Galois theory, including both finite and infinite (algebraic extension) cases. I have also taken a primary course on $p$-adic analysis.

Comment: @HetongXu Oh! So you basically have all the tools you need. Why don't you try looking at the relevant chapters in Neukirch's algebraic number theory book: there's a chapter called "Galois theory of valuations" which should tell you everything you need to know. I'm surprised this stuff isn't all in Serre's book. If there are specific results you need help proving, ask another question here!!

Comment: (Although Neukirch, Serre, etc. will probably only cover the theory for finite extensions. For infinite Galois extensions, Buzzard's notes that you linked to are probably one of the better sources)